# PHP IF/Else Not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have what should be a very simple question.  I am using the following simple PHP if/else statement.  When `nomobile` is not defined or not equal to "true", then the javascript shown below should execute.  If it is equal to true, then it should not execute.  However, the javascript is executing even when `nombobile`=true.  There is probably a minor typo that is messing everything up, but I am driving myself crazy trying to find what is wrong and can't figure it out.

```
<?php
  if ($_GET["nomobile"]!="true")
    {echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "http://www.heliohost.org/m/";
    }
    </script>';}
  else {} ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is a string, set to "true", or a boolean with a value of true?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET['nonmobile'])` produce when added above the `if` statement?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with PHP, but I think a string.  It should be so that if you go to http://www.heliohost.org/?nomobile=true then it does not redirect to /m/

Comment: @andrewsi How exactly would you pass in a `$_GET` variable set to any other type than a string?

Comment: @Christopher Are you sure the screen width is actually a *number* less than or equal to 699?  Have you logged it somewhere?  Because I see the javascript in the source when `?nomobile=true` is tacked onto the end of the URL, and the javascript isn't there when `?nomobile=true` isn't there.  Also, using Firebug, I set a breakpoint on the conditional and it *did* fire.  Check your values.

Comment: @Christopher Are you sure that it's fault of PHP script and not js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you're not checking if the $_GET value is set?  Taking this statement of yours and converting it into code should produce this:

> When nomobile is not defined or not equal to "true"

```
if (!isset($_GET["nomobile"]) || $_GET["nomobile"] != "true"){ ... }
```

There might be issues happening if it's not set.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your Javascript.  Verify that `screen.width` evaluates to a *number* that is less than or equal to 699 by alerting it (or logging it or however you choose to do it).

To clarify, when I try to browse to http://www.heliohost.org/?nomobile=true, I see the Javascript in your code.  If I try to browse to http://www.heliohost.org/ or http://www.heliohost.org/?nomobile=foo, the Javscript isn't there.  Which tells me that your Javascript isn't doing what you expect it to, not that there's a problem with your PHP code.

Comment: The problem is with the PHP being executed when it shouldn't be. The Javascript isn't causing this

Comment: @PriestVallon According to my tests, the PHP code is executing just fine and injecting the javascript when it's supposed to.  Did you test your claim or are you just being argumentative?

Comment: I'm just saying what the question claimed, that the If/Else was the problem and not the JS. Not meant to be argumentative.

Comment: @PriestVallon I think this question is a good example of The XY Problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - and that's why I answered the way I did.

Comment: I fully agree. The question asker not replying or explain things doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_GET['nomobile']) || (isset($_GET['nomobile']) && $_GET['nomobile'] != "true")){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
        document.location = "http://www.heliohost.org/m/";
    }
    </script>';
}
```

Comment: Why call `isset()` twice?  `if (isset($_GET['nomobile']) && $_GET['nomobile'] != 'true')` would suffice.

Comment: Ah, it's just the english language converted to code.

If it doesn't exist or if it is not "true" _when_ it exists.

Answer (score -2):

Remove Double quotes.

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["nomobile"]!=true) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> if (screen.width <= 699) {  document.location = "http://www.heliohost.org/m/"; } </script>';
    }
    else {}
?>
```

Comment: This is **not** the solution, as [it's equivalent to the code in the OP](http://viper-7.com/uS5vv1).